# How to trigger Slack bolt app from external service

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I've developed a slack bot with Slack bolt python framework and Socket Mode is on, the communication between the bot and Slack works fine. However, is there any way to make any communication between the bot and non-slack service? like calling Restful API to trigger specific function declared on the bot.

I've tried to declare event listener and call `chat.postMessage` sending message to IM channel, seems no luck with this.